# Getting Error message when executing terraform : Incompatible API version with plugin. Plugin version: 4, Client versions: [5]

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Failed to instantiate provider "aws" to obtain schema: Incompatible API version with plugin. Plugin version: 4, Client versions: [5]

Comment: What versions of Terraform and the AWS provider are you using? What did you run to get that error? Is that the full error message?

Comment: Thanks,  I was getting above error when I was using terraform_0.12.0-alpha2.  but issue resolved when I reinstalled terraform_0.11.10.

Comment: OP attempted to use an alpha release that states that it can only work with the bundled providers due to a change in protocol.

Comment: I'm getting this error on Terraform `v0.12.0` (stable, no alpha release) with `libvirt` provider. According to [this issue](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt/issues/599) it seems that Terraform has some breaking API changes, which need to be followed by the plugin developer. Think this affects all plugins.